# Knots and Transversality: proving a fundamental property of knot diagrams

Tags: differential-topology, knot-theory, transversality

Let $K:\mathbb{S}^1\times I\to \mathbb{S}^3$ be an **isotopy** of the knots $K_0 = K(\cdot, 0) $ and $K(\cdot, 1).$ Fix $v \in \mathbb{R}^3\subset \mathbb{S}^3$.

I have seen in my knot theory course that we can **perturb** slightly $K$ in such a way that the projection into the orthogonal of $v$,  $$p = \pi_{v^{\perp}} \circ K:\mathbb{S}^1\times I\to v^{\perp}\simeq \mathbb{R}^2$$
satisfies:
1) $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}p(z,t) = 0$ only for a finite number of $t\in I$ and isolated $z$ in $\mathbb{S}^1$

2) $p$ can have double points (also non-tranversal)

3) if $p(z)$ is a triple point then it is a transversal triple point

$p$ has at most double or triple point (i.e. the cardinality of the fiber is at most 3).

This fact is very important in knot theory as is used to introduce Reidemeister moves but I cannot find a proof of it.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are looking for here.  But it might help to know that general position assumes the knot projection has no triple points or tangential double points.

Comment: I agree, but this is true for a projection of a knot, here we are dealing with a projection of an isotopy of knots.